# Delete a single record from an array of nested document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to delete just one contact from the contacts array of a particular user
from mongdb dynamically using nodejs

```
    {
    _id:ObjectId("532737785878v7676747788"),
    firstname:"Mark",
    lastname:"Anthony",
    email:"xyz@gmail.com",
    contacts:[
   {
    _id:ObjectId("678758478fr7889889)",
    firstName:"James",
    lastName:"Cole",
    phoneNo:"09746"
   },
  {
    _id:ObjectId("678758478fr7889889)"
    firstName:"Jane"
    lastName:"Doe"
    phoneNo:"12345"
   }
]
    }
```

I tried this:

```
       User.updateOne(
       {email:'xyz@gmail.com', 'contacts._id':678758478fr7889889},
       { $pull : { contacts : { firstName:'Jane', lastName:'Doe',  phoneNo:'12345'} } },
       {multi:true},
       );
```

I am not getting any error messages and it's not deleting any contact

Comment: Checked your query it's working fine, Can you try after making 'contacts._id' 's value objectId and not a string and try then.

Comment: I am actually getting the contacts._id value as a url parameter from req.params.id. How do i make the 'contacts._id' value objectId?

Comment: @Nedum : what do you've in 'User' model for contacts._id? Also why do you've {multi : true} with updateOne ?

Comment: @srinivasy mongodb automatically adds the id for every contact I create. I used contacts._id  to filter out the contact array object that I want to delete by the _id. I added {multi:true} to updates all documents that meet the query criteria

Comment: @Nedum : yes, that's what I'm trying to explain, $pull would pull out all matching records in array level, but when you use .updateOne() it would be on document level, {multi: true} would also be on document level, I would say .updateOne() and {multi: true} would not go together !! Please check my answer as you mentioned ObjectId's are being created while on inserts!!

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose would use defined schema to create ObjectId's in DB while on writes but it would not use schema on _id(ObjectId's) for find queries, So you've to explicitly say that _id is an ObjectId(). Please have this in your code :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Ignore this if you've already imported.
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

// Assuming id is the value you've got in request.
User.updateOne(
   {email:'xyz@gmail.com', 'contacts._id':new ObjectId(id)},
   { $pull : { contacts : { firstName:'Jane', lastName:'Doe',  phoneNo:'12345'} } });


// you can do the same with `findOneAndUpdate` with options {new: true} which would return updated document, by default it would be false that meant to return old document.
User.findOneAndUpdate(
       {email:'xyz@gmail.com', 'contacts._id':new ObjectId(id)},
       { $pull : { contacts : { firstName:'Jane', lastName:'Doe',  phoneNo:'12345'} } }, {new : true});
```

Comment: @Nedum: Also in same document - if you've two persons with same details(kind of a duplicate record on firstName/lastName/phoneNo), then you need to specify _id as well in the contacts of $pull, that way $pull will only remove that particular object rather than all documents which matches to "{firstName:'Jane', lastName:'Doe',  phoneNo:'12345'}".

Comment: I did everything just as you specified but it didn't work. It didn't throw any error and the selected contact was not deleted

Comment: @Nedum : Ok it's weird, it's working for me, did you check it DB whether it's updated or not, Plus can you print id in code how it is coming in, plus do you've the id which you're passing in filter query(contacts._id) is present in contacts array of which you're deleting !! Can you check how many documents do you've with {contacts._id :ObjectId("678758478fr7889889")}, can you do a count on your collection with that filter and let me know, if it has multiple records then updateOne might be updating one out of those..

Comment: No update was done on the database, the id is coming like this: 5d5ff84b3e8cd6291897829c and yes the id is present in the contacts array and its just for one contact. the count result output is 1

Comment: @Nedum : Ok, So if you do db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({'contacts._id':ObjectId("5d5ff84b3e8cd6291897829c")}), it is returning only one doc ?

Comment: Yes i did User.updateOne({email:userEmail, "contacts._id": new ObjectId(contactId)},
   { $pull : { contacts : { firstName:'Jane', lastName:'Doe',  phoneNo:'12345'} } }).count((err,red)=>{ if(err) throw err; console.log(red);}) it returned 1 on the console

Comment: Yes, every time it would only return one because of updateOne() - either it does update or not irrespective, if it finds a document it does return it. Can you run this query :::>>> db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({'contacts._id':ObjectId("5d5ff84b3e8cd6291897829c")}). and let me know how many docs returned ?

Comment: 1 item was returned

Comment: @Nedum : Ok weird not sure what has gone wrong, just try with findoneandupdate without .count() as I've suggested but really not sure what's happening !! You can directly embed your callback in .findOneAndUpdate() function itself..  Can you give me your complete document returned !!

Comment: I wrote the following: User.findOneAndUpdate({email:userEmail, 'contacts._id':new ObjectId(contactId),},{ $pull : { contacts : {_id:contactId, firstName:firstname, lastName:lastname, phoneNo:telephone } } },(err, result) =>{if(err){console.log(err);return;}else{console.log(result);} }, );

Comment: And it returned the entire record for the particular user: `{ _id: 5d5fadfa71f9511bc0613d87,
  firstname: 'Mark',
  lastname: 'Anthony',
  email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  contacts:
   [ { _id: 5d5ff8373e8cd6291897829b,
       firstName: 'James',
       lastName: 'Cole',
       phoneNo: 09746 },
     { _id: 5d5ff84b3e8cd6291897829c,
       firstName: 'Jane',
       lastName: 'Doe',
       phoneNo: 12345678 } ],
  __v: 14 }`    **NOTE:** The contact._id i used in the query was that of Jane Doe

Comment: @Nedum : That should be ok, Can you try with using new ObjectId() for _id : contactId in $pull as well..

Comment: It returned { n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 } and the contact wasn't deleted

Comment: @Nedum : For contacts._id : you can use any _id that is in contacts array i.e; any persons _id from the document where { firstName:'Jane', lastName:'Doe', phoneNo:'12345'} exists in contacts. But in $pull you need to use exactly the same _id of the person who is being deleted !! Also try executing this in DB directly and check if query is working or not, Plus make sure types of fields match in DB with ones passed from code !! It seems like your phoneNo is "NUMBER" in DB, Are you passing number from code or string ??

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({
        email:'xyz@gmail.com',
        contacts: {
            $elemMatch: {
                "_id": "678758478fr7889889"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $pull: {
            contacts: {
                _id: '678758478fr7889889'
            }
        }
    }

)
```